# Query params with React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to know if it would be possible to apply this logic in a Class Component ? if yes, where would i put the ({ match })

```
const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div> 
    This is a topics
    <div>
    {data.map((item, id) => <div key={id}><Link to={{
      pathname: `${match.url}/${item._id}`,
      state: item
    }}>{item.name}</Link> </div>)}

    </div>
    <hr />
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Topic} />

  </div>
);
```

Comment: it will be available with `this.props.match`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access props in render using `this.props` for a class component

```
class Topics extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const { match } = this.props;
        return (
          <div> 
            This is a topics
            <div>
            {data.map((item, id) => <div key={id}><Link to={{
              pathname: `${match.url}/${item._id}`,
              state: item
            }}>{item.name}</Link> </div>)}

            </div>
            <hr />
            <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Topic} />

          </div>
        );
    }
}
```